# A remote password

Tags: visual, password

I may have forgotten my password for my TV...

All I can remember is its 4 letters long, and only involves letters.

Knowing that I might forget, I hid a clue on the TV remote.

[image: Remote]

> **Can you help me figure out my password?**

Hint:

> The arrows correspond to the numbers, but think about it!

Hint 2:

> The line under the numbers is important

Comment: do you mean 'numbers'? not 'letters'...

Comment: What?! No '0' key??!  :)

Comment: @Ben no it's letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is it:

> AGFD

Reasoning:

> The pad has arrows, like a usual remote, however the four arrows are relocated out of position (clockwise rotation). If we do the same with the keypad we get the following:
>
>    `143`
>
>    `852`
>
>    `769`
>
>  Then we can use the line at the bottom to sum the three rows, as it looks like long addition. This gives 1764. If we take A=1, *and so on*, the answer gives AGFD

Comment: Well done someone finally solved it!

Comment: Just try not to forget your password again!

Comment: :P I just realized, I just posted my password online! :)

Comment: Remotes usually have up, down, left, and right arrows. The left arrow, equivalent to number 4, has moved round to the top, this is equivalent to the number 2 position. Next, the the up arrow, has moved clockwise, into the right arrow position. I hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 4):

Your password

> Reading by arrows in [Calculator spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculator_spelling) is B(6)E(3)l(1)L(7)

Comment: Nice idea but no

Answer (score 3):

You can't find your password...

> ...if you don't LOOK! ('1' as an association to lowercase 'L' + 'O' which the arrows are forming + "OK")

Comment: Sorry no, more complex than that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your password is (just a guess):

> TFES - First letter of the number corresponding to the arrow.

Or

> If the arrow actually points the Number then OSNT (One, Seven, Nine, Three)

Comment: Nice idea but sorry no

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> AGCI

Because

> 1->A, 7->G, 3->C, 9->I

Answer (score 0):

Used some of my knowledge.
Your Password could be:

> 4268 *equals to* ECGI (when A = 0)  ***or***  DBFH (when A = 1)

Answer (score 0):

> 3197 (TONS) .. like if the arrows correspond to the number gives OSNT(1793) and then rearranging the letters gives me TONS

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps:

> Is the answer FOUR? As it consists of 4 letters only.

Comment: No it's a lot more complex

Comment: OKAY??? as in just OK

Comment: Try to consider the hints. If you do so, you'll notice that the solution is not that simple (I suppose).

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.Se Kindly [read the tour page](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and learn to use spoiler tag :)